# Applying CSS to specific section of page

Tags: html, css

I need to apply a pre-existing style-sheet only to elements within a specific div, is this possible?

**Long, drawn-out reason:** We have a page fragment with a css file. We now want to include this page fragment inside another page. Doing so is easy enough but its css and the new page's css conflict. Editing either style-sheet heavily would be difficult as both are large and need to maintain compatibility with how they were before. This brings me to the above question.

Comment: Put the fragment in an iframe?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I was thinking about that but that would get very messy very quick with our js and controllers. It would still be easier than messing with the css in our case. I am still fishing for a simple & clean solution.

Comment: i'd give the wapping div an id or class and add that to every rule in the new css. maybe you can use a replace or regex to add it to every rule at once

Comment: You could have the server modify the css on the fly, and add "#fragment " before every rule, using some regex replace.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Well it seems like your comment may be the winner. Turn that into an answer if you could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place an IFRAME on the page and load the fragment inside it.

```
<iframe id="section" src="fragment.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: Not the ideal solution but certainly the one that contains the changes the most.

Answer (score 5):

do you know http://lesscss.org/ ?
it supports nested rules.
you could nest your entire new css in a new rule (from the class of your div) like that:

```
div#the-new-div{
   div{

   }
   /*** your entire css ***/
}
```

less will compile it to `div#the-new-div div{...}`
i know you probably don't want to implement less into your site but there are standalone less compiler like that: http://digitalpbk.com/less-css/less-css-compiler-windows-lesscexe. then just insert the compiled css

Comment: That's neat. That will warrant another look next time a personal project comes along.

Comment: Yea I used it in one of my projects already and it works really well. Had a smile on my face all the time :)

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot.

You need to change the CSS which should be used in your `<div>`. For example like this:

Add an `id` to your `<div>` e.g. `<div id="foo">` and prefix your CSS rules in the stylesheet you want to use for that `<div>` with `#foo`.

**Disadvantage:**
you need to add the same `id` to your other site's html-tag.

Comment: That is a possible solution but I am afraid there are simply too many rules for that to look right (and if someone adds something to site A's css and doesn't prefix it then site B has an issue